# Einstein Analytics : retrieve datasets via API

Tags: einstein-analytics

I've been trying to retrieve lens and that lens corresponds to a dataset using wave API ( **reference** : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_resources_lenses.htm ).
I'm getting lens in img/png format only.

So my question is, is there any possible way of getting that lens in json/xml format.